# Can't install MongoDB docker on raspberry

Tags: docker

If I want to execute any docker file from https://hub.docker.com/r/library/mongo/tags/ on my raspberry Pi 3B with raspbian stretch installed I always get the same error namely something like :

```
Pulling mongodb (mongo:)...
latest: Pulling from library/mongo
ERROR: no matching manifest for unknown in the manifest list entries
```

How can I resolve this error and what causes it? If you need any more details please let me know I'm pretty new to docker so I don't really know what's relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means that the container that you are trying to pull is not available for the architecture, in this case it would be **linux/arm64**. Maybe there is an image available now. I would search for 'docker mongodb arm64' to see. I see support for mongodb under arm64v8 architecture, which would be in Raspberry Pi 4. Maybe you want to upgrade, as your chip is arm64v7.

This [issue](https://github.com/docker-library/official-images/issues/3835) explains error message in a bit more detail.

Answers under this [issue](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/issues/196) are going to help you run MongoDB under ARM64.